# how to open pdf file in new window which is generated through reportviewer in C#.net

Tags: .net

```
Byte[] results = reportviewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.OutputStream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
Response.End();
```

here by using this code the report is opening in same browser as pdf file. but i want to open this pdf file in a new window. can u help me please..??

Answer (score 1):

you can do a `window.open('newwindow.aspx');` from `java script` and then in the new page write the code to export to PDF on page load. This is the easiest possible solution I can come up with right now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the presentation instead of a link like

```
<a href="/report">click me </a>
```

send it to target _blank

```
<a href="/report" target="_blank">click me </a>
```